# Convergence of the integral $\int\limits_{1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+3}} \right) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Would someone please help me prove that the integral
$$
\int\limits_{1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+3}} \right) \, dx
$$
is convergent?

Thank you.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+3}} = \frac{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x(x+3)}} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{x(x+3)}(\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x})} \le \frac{3}{2x^{3/2}}$$

Comment: @achille hui : this would make a good answer

Answer (score 4):

The integral is equal to $$\int_1^4\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$
, which converges.

Answer (score 2):

Use

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+3}}=\frac{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}}=\frac{3}{(\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x^2+3x}}$$

So, the integrand is positive and $\le \frac{3}{2x\sqrt{x}}$.

Here I use $\sqrt{x^2+3x}>x$ and $\sqrt{x+3}>\sqrt{x}$

So the integral converges by the comparison criterium.

Comment: I assure I did not read the comment above before writing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using $$\int x^m dx=\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}+C$$ for $m+1\ne0$

We have $$\int\left(\frac1{\sqrt x} -\frac1{\sqrt{x+3}} \right) \, dx=2(\sqrt x-\sqrt{x+3})+K$$

$$=2\frac{x-(x+3)}{\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+3}}+K=K-\frac6{\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+3}}$$